# multiple checkbox event listener

Tags: java, checkbox, arraylist

I used a for loop to create multiple checkboxes based on the contents of another ArrayList. now I am trying to make it so when the checkboxes are clicked it will change the attributes of a certain object in an another arraylist. However, when I create the checkboxes in the for loop they all have the same name, so I dont know how to reference each one individually. I also created an ArrayList of Checkboxes thinking I could use this somehow.

```
for(int i =0;i<studentlist1.size();i++)
    {
        JCheckBox chbx = new JCheckBox(studentlist1.get(i).getName());
        panel.add(chbx);
        boxes.add(chbx);
    }
```

Comment: Handle the checkbox event when you create it

Answer (score 0):

Handle the event when you create the checkbox:

```
for(int i =0;i<studentlist1.size();i++)
        {
            JCheckBox chbx = new JCheckBox(studentlist1.get(i).getName());
            panel.add(chbx);
            boxes.add(chbx);

            chbx.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                   //Something
                }
            }
        }
```